# Does all conditions get checked in an if statement even if the first one is false?

Tags: logic, short-circuiting

If I have:

bool foo = false;
bool bar = true;

If(foo && bar)

Doea the if-statement check if bar is true or does it skip it because foo already is false?

Comment: In a C-like language it's short-circuited so only `foo` is checked in your case.

Comment: Depends on the language.  And sometimes on the implementation.

Comment: Thanks :) I have been thinking a lot about this because sometimes the bar could be a function that you like to avoid if foo is false.

Comment: @Husenap To maintain good code readability/quality, i would not suggest doing something like that.

Comment: @addy2012 Well, in my case I had if(foo && Input.Getkeydown())

Comment: In which languages boolean expressions are NOT short-circuited ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff [Wikipedia lists a handful without, and several where it is implementation-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @IMSoP - Thanks.  Fortran, Algol, Pascal and M / MUMPS are the only exceptions.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Plus (from just that short list) Ada, Eiffel, Erlang, and VB where you have to select the right operator, and the obvious ones are eager. It's certainly not something you can assume on seeing an expression written in a language you're new to.

Comment: @IMSoP - That table seems to contain wrong data about Pascal.  I just have checked Delphi's manual: boolean evaluation is short-circuited by default (but may be changed to complete evaluation by means of compiler directive).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Delphi <> Pascal, so it's entirely possible that's a feature that was added. Also, see the footnote: "ISO Pascal allows but does not require short-circuiting" - so compilers of even the standard language *could* be implemented that way, but you can't rely on it one way or the other. (Which is consistent with having a compiler directive, come to think of it.) Again, key point is, *you can't assume one way or another, given an unknown language*, because it's far from universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and whether it will happen depends on:

- the language you are programming in
- in some cases, the implementation (where the language definition neither mandates nor prohibits it)
- in some cases, the exact situation (where the language explicitly allows but does not guarantee it, and the implementation may choose whether to short-circuit on a case-by-case basis)
- the exact operator you use (some languages provide two ways of writing "and", one "eager" and one "short-circuit"

Note that it is not a property of the `if` statement, which is just taking a single boolean expression which has resulted from you using logical operators; the expression could equally be assigned to a boolean variable, passed as a function parameter, etc.